# How to make subsite available to all without users

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have an internal sharepoint intranet site. We are using Sharepoint Online 2013.  We would like to create a subsite that is only available to our hourly workers, but does not allow them to have access to any other part of our intranet.  Is it possible to do this without having to create a special user account for them?  Or would it be best to just create a separate site outside of our normal intranet site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Damjan's answer, you'll want to break the permissions inheritance at the site level for the sub site so you can have different permissions at that level. This will let you trim the permissions so the hourly employee's can access the sub-site but not the parent.

Comment: Thanks this is the direction I was leaning, just was not sure if there was someway I could get around having to create a user account.  Our hourly employees will not be having their own individual accounts.  They would be accessing this subsite from a common "public" kiosk or computer in the cafeteria.  I will be creating a generic user for each kiosk.  Unfortuantely periodically that user will have to be logged back in and I was hoping to avoid that but not sure I can.

Comment: Depends on how your network/domain is set up. You can configure it so that SharePoint logs in automatically using the logged in Windows user, which sounds like is what you want to achieve but that goes a bit beyond SharePoint and into sys-admin stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate security group, add all of those users to the group and give the group read permissions on subsite. That way they will only have access to the subsite and will not be able to see any other part of the portal.
If your hourly users don't have office 365 accounts, you can add them as external users to the group (use their Live ID accounts).

Comment: Unless the Group Everyone is used for security in any other site,web or list. So you need to check everything